# HGET in private method not returning hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

Some reason my `hget` is not finding or returning a hash I set in a public method. I can't figure out why.

This is all in one controller that inherits from `ApplicationController`, which is where I define my redis initializer:

```
def redis
   Thread.current[:redis] ||= Redis.new
end
```

Then in my controller I do this to set the hash:

```
def return_customer
  email = params["email"]
  customer = Customer.find_by(email: email)
  credit_amount = customer.credit_amount.to_f
  customer_data = {email: email, customer_id: customer.id, credit_amount: credit_amount}
  redis.hset("shop:#{customer.shop.id}:customer", customer_data, customer_data.inspect)
  render json: customer
end
```

Then finally I have this private method I use in other methods in the same controller, this is the part that's not working:

```
private

def get_customer_from_redis
  shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: params["shop"])
  customer_info = redis.hget("shop:#{shop.id}:customer", customer_data)
  eval(customer_info)
end
```

This is the error that's returned

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you rather than using `.inspect` use `.to_json` like this:

```
def return_customer
  email = params["email"]
  customer = Customer.find_by(email: email)
  credit_amount = customer.credit_amount.to_f
  customer_data = {email: email, customer_id: customer.id, credit_amount: credit_amount}
  redis.set("shop:#{customer.shop.id}:customer", customer_data.to_json)
  render json: customer
end
```

And then in your private method

```
def get_customer_from_redis
  shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: params["shop"])
  customer_info = redis.get("shop:#{shop.id}:customer", customer_data)
  JSON.parse(customer_info) if customer_info
end
```

Comment: Yeah, `inspect` is a highly Ruby-specific form and isn't something you can easily and safely deserialize. JSON is much better.

Comment: thanks.. its still not working though.. I get this error.. "TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):"

Comment: @ToddT I updated my answer. Now get_custom_from_redis method won't throw an error because customer_info could be nil. Could you please try it now.